# ExtJS--set textfield value to first of the month

Tags: extjs

I am trying to default the value of a textfield to the first of the current month

```
{
  xtype:"textfield",
  fieldLabel:"Effective Date",
  name:"effDate",
  labelAlign:"top",
  editable:false,
  value: Ext.Date.getFirstDateOfMonth()//throws error saying cannot read property "getFullYear" of undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass date to this [function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-getFirstDateOfMonth)

```
value: Ext.Date.getFirstDateOfMonth(new Date()) // for example
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gfh)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the first date of the current month, you should add new Date() as a parameter.

```
{
    xtype:"textfield",
    fieldLabel:"Effective Date",
    name:"effDate",
    labelAlign:"top",
    editable:false,
    value: Ext.Date.getFirstDateOfMonth(new Date())
}
```